# Ocultar campos no iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou gerando um relatório no iReport e tenho uma dúvida. Em um pedaço do relatório tenho um bloco de endereço de entrega. Gostaria de exibir esse bloco APENAS quando o endereço for diferente de vazio ou diferente de nulo, ou seja, quando for vazio todo o bloco ficaria oculto, sem o espaçamento em branco.
Reforçando que não é o valor da variável que preciso ocultar, e sim o bloco onde ela se encontra ser ocultada se o mesmo estiver vazio.

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Este bloco onde fica o seu endereço de entrega está em uma banda separada como summary ou ele está junto com outros itens na detail por exemplo 
?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Hebert.
Ele está na band principal (detail). Acredito que terei que refazer o relatório, separando por bands para obter o resultado que espero. O bloco de endereço precisa estar separado por band para eu conseguir ocultá-lo. Como surgiram outras prioridades acabei deixando de lado essa questão, mas depois de algumas pesquisas cheguei a essa conclusão